# Retrieve the list of alla jpg file of a directory

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding a file with a specific name with any extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202203/finding-a-file-with-a-specific-name-with-any-extension)

i've this code for put into an array all the files contained into a directory

```
$directory =  "./";
$ourDirList = scandir($directory); 
$arraylistafiles=array();

foreach($ourDirList as $ourItem) 
{  
   if (is_file($ourDir . $ourItem)) 
   {$arraylistafiles[]=$ourItem;}
}
```

but if i want to put only the file that have ".jpg" extension, what i can do?

Comment: "what can I do?" well, you could use the search function because this has been answered a dozens times or more.

Answer (score 6):

Using PHP's [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) you can avoid the `is_file()` call because `glob` will only return files that actually exist in the directory. There is **no need** to create a UDF (user defined function) in your case.

```
$dir = './';
foreach(glob($dir.'*.jpg') as $file) {
  print $file . "\n";
}
```

**UPDATE**

From your comment it's clear that you don't understand how `glob()` works. You can achieve what you're trying to do like this:

`$arraylistafiles = glob($dir.'*.jpg');`

Comment: i wrote
  foreach(glob($ourDir.'*.jpg') as $ourItem)
   {  
      if (is_file($ourDir . $ourItem)) 
      {$arraylistafiles[]=$ourItem;}
   }  

but donesn't work

Comment: You don't need all that extra code ... `glob()` gives you the array of files (`$arraylistafiles`) you're trying to create. Also, "doesn't work" is ambiguous -- an actual error message is infinitely more helpful. You could do the same thing like this: `$arraylistafiles = glob($dir.'*.jpg');`

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(is_file($ourDir.$ourItem) && substr($ourItem,-4) == '.jpg') {
     //
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow function.

```
public function getFileList($dirpath,$list_ignore,$list_allowed_ext)
    {
        $filelist = array();
        if ($handle = opendir(dirname ($dirpath))) 
        {
           while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
              {
                  if (!is_dir($file) && !in_array($file,$list_ignore) && in_array(strtolower(end(explode('.',$file))),$list_allowed_ext))
                    {
                        $filelist[] = $file;
                    }
              }
            closedir($handle);
        }

        return $filelist;
    }
```

Implementation will be looks like..

```
$fileTypes = array ("jpg");
$list_ignore = array ('.','..');
$fileList = getFileList("./",$list_ignore,$fileTypes);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check for the file extension for the file in foreach array. . If the extension is jpg then add that item into the new array. . . Hope you understand. .